# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (jquery.dataTables.js:4214)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to reproduce this example: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

I linked the 3 files :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
```

And put the HTML of the example in my web page but I have an error :

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (jquery.dataTables.js:4214) :

```
// Check it has a unit character already
return s.match(/\d$/) ?
```

Ideas ?

Thx

Comment: looks like `s` is undefined... what is the expected value of `s`

Comment: Here the function : http://pastebin.com/FEC7uqPq
With Chrome

Comment: I replaced <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 by <script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your example ACCORDING to two cases :

1. ON Local :  `file:///home/abdennour/path/to/page.html`
2. On Local Server : `http://localhost/path/to/page.html`

I ve got the same error with the first case , However , there is no problem with the second case .

THerefore , you must use **Http server**, such as apache, to test your code

Because :
 if you are in the first case , this code  :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

will be handled as :

```
<script src="file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Howerver , if you are in the second case , that code will be handled as :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using a http server 

Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian); X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u8

Comment: I have put "http:" and always the same problem :(

Comment: $ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  3 2014 12:20:28

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. I switched the order of declarations to this and it's solved my problem. My tables seem to display and operate ok with the following decalrations.

```
<script src=\"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js\"></script>"
<script src=\"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js\"></script>"
```